# How to mark up a layout blocks with the CSS property "display:flex;"?

Tags: html, css

In one of the project decided to use the new CSS property "display:flex;". After reading many articles and did not understand whether it is possible to make such a layout blocks without violating HTML code.

See image:
[image]

```css
.container {
    width:910px;
    display:flex;
}

figure {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:180px;
}

figure:first-child {
    width:600px;
    height:370px;
}

figure:first-child figcaption {
    width:590px;
}

figure figcaption {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding:5px;
    width:290px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x370" alt="">
        <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    
    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x180" alt="">
        <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    
    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x180" alt="">
        <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</figcaption>
    </figure>

</div>
```

Also there is a ready code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jeen/vzjhybh0/1/)

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to use CSS columns https://jsfiddle.net/vzjhybh0/4/

```
    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x370" alt="">
        <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x180" alt="">
        <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x180" alt="">
        <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</figcaption>
    </figure>

</div>

.container {
    width:1100px;
    height:400px;
     -webkit-columns: 2;
}

figure {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:180px;
}

figure:first-child {
    width:600px;
    height:370px;
}

figure:first-child figcaption {
    width:590px;
}

figure figcaption {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding:5px;
    width:290px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

Comment: So it is understandable, but not to break the HTML code?

Comment: @JeenJay I dont think you can do it with flex, but css columns would do, see https://jsfiddle.net/vzjhybh0/4/

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I think that it is necessary to use a variant with an additional block in the HTML code.